# What is Salesforce Daily api limit per user per 24 hours?

Tags: rest-api, api, integration, httprequest, limitexception

According to
[Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.html),
Salesforce Unlimited editions have a limit of 5,000 API calls Per License Type, per 24 hours and the total API calls per 24 hours are:

> 100,000 + (number of licenses x calls per license type) + purchased
> API Call Add-Ons

It's a bit confusing, does this means that a single user can't make API calls more than 5000 in a 24 hours period But, I tested it and we were able to make more than 10k Api calls in 24 hours.Now the question is there a limit to the number of api calls that a user can make in 24 hours.If yes, What is it?If no, can a single user utilise all the 24 hours limit of the organization?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [API Request Limits documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) goes into a bit more detail

> Limits and allocations are enforced against the aggregate of all API calls made to the org in a 24-hour period. Limits and allocations are not on a per-user basis.

> ### Example API Usage Metering Calculations
>
> The following examples illustrate API usage metering calculations for several scenarios.
>
> - For an Enterprise Edition org with 15 Salesforce licenses, the request limit is 115,000 requests (100,000 plus 15 licenses x 1,000 calls).
> - For a Developer Edition org that made 14,500 calls at 5:00 AM Wednesday, 499 calls at 11:00 PM Wednesday, only one more call can successfully be made until 5:00 AM Thursday.

In a nutshell, you get 100k requests + (per-license allocation * # of licenses). That makes up a resource pool. Each api request made by a user counts against the pool for 24 hours. Salesforce uses a rolling window, so a request made yesterday (over 24 hours ago) no longer counts towards your limit.

Salesforce also uses their threshold-based approach to limits for api requests (like they do with cpu time, and several other limits). If your pod is "healthy", and you haven't gone over your limit *too* often, Salesforce can allow you to go over that limit by a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The API call limit is an org-wide limit. It scales *with* your user license count, but is not applied on a per-user basis.

> Now the question is there a limit to the number of api calls that a user can make in 24 hours

No, the API call limit is a bucket for all users.

Comment: Salesforce Unlimited editions have a limit of 5,000 API calls Per License Type. What exactly is this limit then?

Comment: It is the value of the equation given in your question. 100,000 + (license count * license allocation) + additional purchases.